# Reading a pointer declaration

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int daytab[2][13];
    int (*daytab)[13];
    int *px;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am studying pointers and having difficulty reading the `int (*daytab)[13]` declaration.
`int *px` is read as `px` is a pointer to a `int`.

How do you read `int (*daytab)[13]`?

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244680/what-do-parentheses-in-a-c-variable-declaration-mean

Comment: See [this beautiful article](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations).

Comment: daytab is pointer to array of 13 int.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation

Comment: In declaration `int (*daytab)[13]`, `daytab` is pointer to an int array of 13 elements. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20120253/1673391)

Comment: shouldnt it be like int[13] *daytab ,to make sense as int *px?

Comment: Still a pointer to an *int* (array).

Comment: you can parse it by this website: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: `int int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  is error removed one `int`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html): is a technique known as the **Clockwise/Spiral Rule** which enables any C programmer to parse in their head any C declaration!

There are three simple steps to follow:

1. Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when encountering the following elements replace them with the corresponding English statements:

   `[X]` or `[]`
   => Array `X` size of... or Array undefined size of...

   (`type1`, `type2`)
   => function passing `type1` and `type2` returning...
   `*`
   => pointer(s) to
2. Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered.
3. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first! It will make sense;

---

```
     +---------+              
     | +-----+ |     
     | ^     | |      ( daytab)        // daytab
int (*daytab)  [13];  (*daytab)        // daytab is a pointer
 ^   ^       | |      (*daytab)[13]    // daytab is a pointer to an array of 13
 |   |       | |      int(*daytab)[13] // daytab is a pointer to an array of 13 ints 
 |   +-------+ |            
 +-------------+
```

Here are some answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20635774/2455888). Read them all.

Comment: a picture is worth thousand words!! Nice expalanation in few words.

Comment: what you say about? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error)

Comment: I would say to read the comments by Jonathan Leffler and Legends2k.

Comment: well that conversation ends nowhere

Comment: Please keep in mind that this rule is not universal.